# what type of text stored in img field bytea type cannot display using php

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, postgresql-9.5

i have no idea what data is in the field img bytea.. because this data comes from the previous developer using delphi language i just want to display it in my php code

I tried to use pg_unescape_bytea() but only a text nothings change

[image]

Comment: it look like a raw image file https://fileinfo.com/extension/jfif

Comment: sidenote: there's a special place in hell reserved for devs who store binary files as database elements

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the img value inside a function called base64_decode(img) then you`ll get a text, this is a image base64, then get this text and put it inside a src img like "> this probably will show u up the image.

If it doesnt help you  you could try this https://github.com/cc-archive/xmp-jpeg-php/blob/master/pjmt/JFIF.php to convert and manipulate Jfif image format.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: too complicated is there any option to directly upload to a specific directory like file_put_contents?

Comment: Yes its possible, but already is data inserted in database, so you can set a default to work as another one did, or change, if you change you can convert all the images in database in files and upload to dir, if u do it the database will be light.